# Port code from JS to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpacker

I using honeybadger for error tracking

In js file I have this code.

```
 var Honeybadger = require('honeybadger-js/honeybadger');

Honeybadger.configure({
  apiKey: *********,
  environment: process.env.RAILS_ENV || 'development',
  revision: process.env.GIT_COMMIT || 'master',
  debug: true
});
```

I need to use it in ts script

But when I copy code I have errors

> file: 'file:///Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/falco-web/app/javascript/packs/hello_typescript.ts'
>   severity: 'Error'
>   message: 'Cannot find name 'require'.'
>   at: '3,19'
>   source: 'ts'
>   code: '2304'
>
> file:
>   'file:///Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/falco-web/app/javascript/packs/hello_typescript.ts'
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'Cannot find name 'process'.' at: '7,16'
>   source: 'ts' code: '2304'

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
import Honeybadger from 'honeybadger-js/honeybadger';
```

Comment: Okay, so it fixed only `require`, but how to fix process error?

Comment: Try restarting your build process.